# Raspbery Pi case with Real Time Clock and battery power

Tags: raspberry-pi, real-time-clock, battery

I have found a few old Kickstart projects, such as [this](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/geekroo/pipeye-an-advanced-battery-hat-to-power-your-raspb/posts/1323876), which consist of a case (not on-topic), containing a Real Time Clock and battery power for the Pi.

Some have a few extra features, such as a display, extra USB ports, or solar power panel, etc.

Does anyone know of anything with at least the capabilities of the referenced project? (or even where I can buy one of those)

Comment: Did you check adafruit?  I haven’t browsed for pi stuff in a few years (I own like 6 pi’s in different models,I just haven’t needed anything for a few years) but they used to carry interesting things like that....

Comment: YUp. That's the first place I checked. Then Pi Hut.

Comment: Not battery, but RTC, there are now a bunch of them on eBay. No point linking,as they die quickly, but seller `autoaccessori-online` has many. Again, with RTC, but not battery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PiJuice HAT](https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pijuice-standard) includes a battery solution for the Pi, and has a built-in RTC. There's additional features/add-ons available as well.

Comment: Pricier than ***five !!!*** Pi Zero Ws - but it's just what I asked for and I know of no alternatives. Thanks you very much.